# Centralise center footer & flush right right footer in landscape multicol mode

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, multicol, landscape

How do I centralise the center footer and flush right the right footer?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tabularx,array,booktabs} % for stretching tables to page width
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % for centering tables in tabularx
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}} % for vertical space in tabularx
\newcommand{\heading}[1]{\bfseries\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}} % for a header in tables
\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}} % for vertically centering text in tables
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pstricks-add} % for geogebra
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}% for framed rounded boxes
\tcbset{colframe=black,colback=white,colupper=black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,nobeforeafter,center title,size=small}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{framed}% for framed standard boxes
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lfoot{Left footer}
\cfoot{Center footer}
\rfoot{Right footer}

\linespread{1.2}


\newenvironment{Figure}
  {\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}}
  {\endminipage\par\medskip}




\newenvironment{cframed}
{
\begin{framed}\begin{center}
}
{
\end{center}\end{framed}
}




% This sets page margins to .5 inch if using letter paper, and to 1cm
% if using A4 paper. (This probably isn't strictly necessary.)
% If using another size paper, use default 1cm margins.
\ifthenelse{\lengthtest { \paperwidth = 11in}}
    { \geometry{top=.5in,left=.5in,right=.5in,bottom=.5in} }
    {\ifthenelse{ \lengthtest{ \paperwidth = 297mm}}
        {\geometry{top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm} }
        {\geometry{top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm} }
    }

% Turn off header and footer
%\pagestyle{empty}




% Redefine section commands to use less space
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{0mm}%
                                {-1ex plus -.5ex minus -.2ex}%
                                {0.5ex plus .2ex}%x
                                {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{0mm}%
                                {-1explus -.5ex minus -.2ex}%
                                {0.5ex plus .2ex}%
                                {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{0mm}%
                                {-1ex plus -.5ex minus -.2ex}%
                                {1ex plus .2ex}%
                                {\normalfont\small\bfseries}}
\makeatother

% Define BibTeX command
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

% Don't print section numbers
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.5ex}


% -----------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\raggedright
\footnotesize
\begin{multicols}{3}


% multicol parameters
% These lengths are set only within the two main columns
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.25pt}
\setlength{\premulticols}{1pt}
\setlength{\postmulticols}{1pt}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2pt}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]


\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is normal behavior of `fancyhdr`, so since you are not getting that result, it means something else is in your very long and [not so Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) is the blame.

The problems is that you are changing the page-geometry after setting up the the headers. Simply moving that part to after any `geometry`-changes will sort this out.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tabularx,array,booktabs} % for stretching tables to page width
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % for centering tables in tabularx
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}} % for vertical space in tabularx
\newcommand{\heading}[1]{\bfseries\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}} % for a header in tables
\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}} % for vertically centering text in tables
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pstricks-add} % for geogebra
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}% for framed rounded boxes
\tcbset{colframe=black,colback=white,colupper=black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,nobeforeafter,center title,size=small}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{framed}% for framed standard boxes

\linespread{1.2}


\newenvironment{Figure}
  {\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}}
  {\endminipage\par\medskip}




\newenvironment{cframed}
{
\begin{framed}\begin{center}
}
{
\end{center}\end{framed}
}




% This sets page margins to .5 inch if using letter paper, and to 1cm
% if using A4 paper. (This probably isn't strictly necessary.)
% If using another size paper, use default 1cm margins.
\ifthenelse{\lengthtest { \paperwidth = 11in}}
    { \geometry{top=.5in,left=.5in,right=.5in,bottom=.5in} 
    }
    {\ifthenelse{ \lengthtest{ \paperwidth = 297mm}}
        {\geometry{top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm} }
        {\geometry{top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm} }
    }

% Turn off header and footer
%\pagestyle{empty}




% Redefine section commands to use less space
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{0mm}%
                                {-1ex plus -.5ex minus -.2ex}%
                                {0.5ex plus .2ex}%x
                                {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{0mm}%
                                {-1explus -.5ex minus -.2ex}%
                                {0.5ex plus .2ex}%
                                {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{0mm}%
                                {-1ex plus -.5ex minus -.2ex}%
                                {1ex plus .2ex}%
                                {\normalfont\small\bfseries}}
\makeatother

% Define BibTeX command
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

% Don't print section numbers
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.5ex}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lfoot{Left footer}
\cfoot{Center footer}
\rfoot{\hfill Right footer}


% -----------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\raggedright
\footnotesize
\begin{multicols}{3}



% multicol parameters
% These lengths are set only within the two main columns
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.25pt}
\setlength{\premulticols}{1pt}
\setlength{\postmulticols}{1pt}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2pt}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]


\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```